# Delete data HQL with setParameter or setParametrList strangeness

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g, hql

I have a simple table and try to delete data by array of ids.

```
Integer[] arrayIDs = {1,2,3}; //External ids as parameteres
    Query deleteItemsQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE Items WHERE id IN (:idsDeletingItems)"); //(in this row exception)
deleteItemsQuery.setParameterList("idsDeletingItems", arrayIDs);
deleteItemsQuery.executeUpdate();
```

And my app throw exception

I also try with deleting 1 parameter. For example

```
Query deleteItemsQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE Items WHERE id = '1'");
deleteItemsQuery.executeUpdate();
```

And with that variant no problem.

But when I do next I have also exception

```
Integer myID = 1;
Query deleteItemsQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE Items WHERE id = (:myID)");
    deleteItemsQuery.setParameter("myID", myID);
    deleteItemsQuery.executeUpdate();
```

I use this dialect org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect. Any ideas?

Exception

```
exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: antlr.collections.AST.getLine()I
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:295)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy.execute(DelegatingActionProxy.java:113)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    com.epam.testapp.presentation.filter.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:44)
    com.epam.testapp.presentation.filter.CommandFilter.doFilter(CommandFilter.java:58)


root cause 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: antlr.collections.AST.getLine()I
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.generateNamedParameter(HqlSqlWalker.java:956)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.parameter(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4821)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1347)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4297)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3772)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1947)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:794)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.deleteStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:443)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:263)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:219)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:197)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1736)
    com.epam.testapp.database.NewsHibernateDAO.remove(NewsHibernateDAO.java:89)
    com.epam.testapp.presentation.action.NewsAction.delete(NewsAction.java:150)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy.execute(DelegatingActionProxy.java:113)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: What is the exception? Is "id" integer in the database?

Comment: What exception do you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it like this

```
Integer myID = 1;
Query deleteItemsQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE Items WHERE id =:myID");
    deleteItemsQuery.setParameter("myID", myID);
    deleteItemsQuery.executeUpdate();
```

and make sure no space between ":" and "myID" else it will another error.

Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: I guess , you have mixed incompatible versions of Hibernate jars (probably ANTLR jar has a wrong version). Please check compatible versions of struts , hibernate and antlr.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem once and worked around it by adding the opening and closing brace to my parameter in stead of placing it directly in the HQL.

Comment: I also do                                                        `Query deleteNewsQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE News WHERE id = (:myID)"); deleteNewsQuery.setParameter("myID", myID);` And it doesn't help